# Why did future Janeway not tell Voyager about transwarp-hubs during Scorpion I&II?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, star-trek-voyager

For the hundredth time I am re-watching Star Trek: Voyager now, and I just wondered about the following:

In *Endgame* future Janeway travels back in time to lead Voyager home through a Borg transwarp-hub, which turned out to be a pretty dangerous undertaking. Years earlier though, during the war between Species 8472 and the Borg shown in *Scorpion I&II*, Janeway traded the modified borg-nanoprobes in form of a weapon for save passage through borg-controlled space. It seems to me, had she known about the transwarp-hubs, she could have just requested save travel directly to Federation space. It would have gone way faster and requires only knowledge of those hubs: Get a sphere to Voyager, let them open a conduit to a hub, go through and transmit the blueprints after. Seems to me everyone would've benefitted from this. Well, except Species 8472.

So why take the difficult approach of upgrading Voyager with tech from the future (by the way, where the heck was the timetravel-police we've seen in one of the other episodes?) and sending them through a hub, instead of just making past-Janeway trade the nanoprobes for a route to earth?

Comment: Regarding the "tine-travel" police, I'd say it's sloppy writing.

Comment: Past Janeway wouldn't have accepted the offer. At this point she's still too ethical for her own good.